# Elasticsearch ScrollId returns no document

Tags: c#, asp.net, elasticsearch

I'm facing a strange issue with Elastisearch and scroll. I'm trying to get 50 192 records from my index but `scrollId` is returning 0 so my loop doesn't execute. There is my code :

```
var results = new List<MyModelList>();
var scanResults = client.Search<MyModel>(s => s
     .Index("myindex")
     .Type("MyIndexType")
     .From(0)
     .Size(2000)
     .Query(q => q.QueryString(qs => qs.Query(query)))
     .Scroll("5m")
   );

var resultsscroll = client.Scroll<MyModel>("10m", scanResults.ScrollId);
while (resultsscroll.Documents.Any())
 {
   foreach (var doc in results)
   {
     results.Add(doc);
   }
   resultsscroll = client.Scroll<MyModel>("10m", resultsscroll.ScrollId);
 }
return results;
```

When putting a break point, I can see that `scanResults` is set to 2000, but next, `resultsscroll` is at 0. What am I doing wrong? Followed the official doc, and make some search, seems everyone is using it this way. If someone as an idea of why it is not working it would be nice.

You will see that I've removed :

```
.SearchType(Nest.SearchType.Scan)
```

From my query, because if I let it, `scanResults` is set to 0. Don't understand why neither.

Comment: Which version of the elastic search are you using? and version of Nest?

Comment: Have you checked resultsscroll.Hits property?

Comment: @AmanB hits property is null, my version of elasticsearch is 5.5 and nest 1.6.0

Comment: @Christan, that's a really old version of Nest, you should be using Nest 5.5. Can you please provide the values of scanResults object? is the search result successful? do you get any scrollId?

Comment: I know it's old but last time we tried to update, a lot of issues came ! And yes, i get a scroll Id and scan result is Total 50 192. But it's not working after that, still null in resultsscroll.Made in a different way and it's working now ! But i'd like to understand why it's not with the code above.

Comment: You can create the same request in [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to verify if it is a problem with your server or your code

Comment: If it is a problem on the server side you can check the logs if there are any errors there.

Comment: Out of curiosity how did you make it work?

Comment: @AmanB sorry for the late answer, but i posted answer to my own question if you want to see how i fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

This is how if fixes my issue (also here on Aman's demand).

```
//Settings
var maxQuery = 50000;

//Connection
var client = ConnectElasticClient();

//Prepare Result
var results = new List<ModelDL>();

var countHits = (int)client.Search<Model>(s => s.Index("MyIndex").Type("MyType")
    .Query(q => q.QueryString(qs => qs.Query(query)))).Total;

//First Query 
var response =
    client.Search<Model>(s => s.Index("MyIndex").Type("MyType").Size(maxQuery)
        .Query(q => q.QueryString(qs => qs.Query(query))));

if (countHits <= maxQuery)
{
   return results;
}

var cpt = maxQuery;

for (var i = 0; i < ((countHits - maxQuery) / maxQuery); i++)
{
    var res =
        client.Search<Model>(s => s.Index("MyIndex").Type("MyType").From(cpt).Size(maxQuery)
            .Query(q => q.QueryString(qs => qs.Query(query))));
    cpt += maxQuery;
    results.AddRange(res.Documents.Select(x => new EntrepriseSireneDL(x)));
}

var lastScrollSize = countHits - cpt;

var r =
    client.Search<Model>(s => s.Index("MyIndex").Type("MyType").From(cpt).Size(lastScrollSize)
        .Query(q => q.QueryString(qs => qs.Query(query))));
results.AddRange(r.Documents.Select(x => new ModelDL(x)));

return results;
```

This way, i get everything i want as i want it.